# How to do multiple logistic regressions in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I have created a graph with the following code and data:

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(x=Score, y=Year, col=Position)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE).

Year   Position   Score
2010   QB         16.5
2011   QB         15.4
2012   QB         16.1
2013   QB         14.3
2014   QB         13.8
2010   RB         14.2
2011   RB         13.9
2012   RB         13.9
2013   RB         11.8
2014   RB         11.6
2010   WR         11.4
2011   WR         12.4
2012   WR         10.4
2013   WR         8.8
2014   WR         9.7
```

[image]

My goal is to do a similar graph with the data below, except with a logistic regression since the Y-value (Score1) is binary. I tried changing the `method="lm"` to `method="Binominal"` but that hasn't worked. Can anyone help? I'd prefer that it's done in ggplot so that the graphs look as similar in composition as possible.

```
Score1 Position Score2
0   QB         16.5
0   QB         15.4
1   QB         16.1
0   QB         14.3
1   QB         13.8
1   RB         14.2
1   RB         13.9
1   RB         13.9
0   RB         11.8
0   RB         11.6
1   WR         11.4
1   WR         12.4
0   WR         10.4
1   WR         8.8
1   WR         9.7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of doing this would be

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(x=Score2, y=Score1, col=Position)) +
+     geom_smooth(method="glm",method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se=FALSE)
```

however, Score1 should be 0 or 1, so you'd have to transform your classes and potentially make multiple plots.

Answer (score 2):

Use `stat_smooth`instead of `geom_smooth`, like this:

`ggplot(data.frame, aes(x=Score, y=Year, col=Position)) + stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial",se=fALSE)`

EDIT: You might need `qplot`, there is an example for logistic regression at the end of the following link https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.0/topics/stat_smooth